# stack level too deep error when I render partial from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page, taxons#show, that lists many products. When you click a product the user is directed to products#show by default, where the partial _cart_local.html.erb is rendered. However, I've changed the UX so that when you click on a product in taxons#show a lightbox pops up in the same window, so inside the taxons controller and show view. But when I also try to render the *cart*_local partial inside the lightbox I get a stack level too deep error.

Here's the file in question. I understand it could also be occurring from somewhere else. What usually causes this type of error?

```
<%= form_for :order, :url => populate_orders_path do |f| %>
```

```
<% if product.has_variants? %>
  <div id="product-variants" class="columns five alpha">
    <h6 class="product-section-title"><%= t(:variants) %></h6>
    <ul>
      <% has_checked = false
      product.variants.active(current_currency).each_with_index do |v,index|
        next if v.option_values.empty? || (!v.in_stock && !Spree::Config[:show_zero_stock_products])
        checked = !has_checked && (v.in_stock || Spree::Config[:allow_backorders])
        has_checked = true if checked %>
        <li>
          <%= radio_button_tag "products[#{product.id}]", v.id, checked, :disabled => !v.in_stock && !Spree::Config[:allow_backorders], 'data-price' => v.price_in(current_currency).display_price %>
          <label for="<%= ['products', product.id, v.id].join('_') %>">
            <span class="variant-description">
              <%= variant_options v %>
            </span>
            <% if variant_price v %>
              <span class="price diff"><%= variant_price v %></span>
            <% end %>
          </label>
        </li>
      <% end%>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end%>

<% if product.price_in(current_currency) and !product.price.nil? %>
  <div data-hook="product_price" class="columns five <% if !product.has_variants? %> alpha <% else %> omega <% end %>">

    <div id="product-price">
      <h6 class="product-section-title"><%= t(:price) %></h6>
      <div><span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= product.price_in(current_currency).display_price %></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="add-to-cart">
      <% if product.on_sale? %>      
        <%= number_field_tag (product.has_variants? ? :quantity : "variants[#{product.master.id}]"),
          1, :class => 'title', :in => 1..product.on_hand, :min => 1 %>
        <%= button_tag :class => 'large primary', :id => 'add-to-cart-button', :type => :submit do %>
          <%= t(:add_to_cart) %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= content_tag('strong', t(:out_of_stock)) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
    <div id="product-price">
      <br>
      <div><span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= t('product_not_available_in_this_currency') %></span></div>
    </div>
<% end %>    

</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is usually a recursion gone bad.

Either the partial calls itself, or one of the functions used within the partials calls itself (with a bad/no break condition).

Comment: Hard to say. There is so much going on in this partial. try rendering an empty partial and see if it still occurs. If not, the problem origins here. You can then use this strategy within this file to get to the sections that causes the error. (`devide and conquer` applied to debugging).

Comment: Thank you. I rendered an empty partial and it loaded fine. Last question then I'll leave you alone...are there any clues to look for within a file that is doing this?

Comment: since i do not see any further partials within this: every call to functions you wrote yourself. external gems usually work correctly, unless treated wrongly (ie. bad parameters). Just try uncommenting blocks of code and watch if the problem occurs or not. everytime the problem does not occur, the problematic piece of code was within the deactivated region. When you have the line that breaks your application, you can investigate it. Other options would be to look at the produced stack trace or use the ruby debugger to go through each line.